# Test the position of the image in map using sikuli webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I'm not sure it is something possible to do with sikuli webdriver. I have searched over the internet but couldn't find any article about this matter. What I want to do is to get the latitude and longitude of the given image in the map for testing purpose. Is that something possible to do with sikuli web driver. If not is there any other solution to test maps ? 
Any hint or link for a tutorial would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a specific example? There is an example of [using the SikuliFirefoxDriver with Google Maps](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver) on the Wiki.

Comment: Thanks for the response seumas. I have looked that example. My case is, it is a map with vehicles(images) and I need to test those vehicles are locating in correct places on the map. I tried to get lat and log of the images but still I couldn't find a proper way for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like this: 
In de sikuli doc you can find a bit of info on how to grab location: [doc.sikuli on Location](http://doc.sikuli.org/location.html)

Example code: 
(Sikuli with Python)

```
class Cords():
     def __init__(self):
          # Find the image
          imageLoc = find("image1.png")
          # Get the X, Y position
          x = imageLoc.getX() # For example: x = 499
          y = imageLoc.getY() # For example: y = 811
          # Print the positions
          print(x, y)
          # Look if the image is on this given position. 
          if (imageLoc.getX() == 499) and (imageLoc.getY() == 811):
               print('Correct')
          else:
               print('Incorrect')
```